# How do I update a text value of NULL to an actual NULL value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I imported a table into my SQL Server 2017 database. The table contained the text value of "NULL" in fields with no other value. What is the syntax of the query that will replace the text values of "NULL" with nothing?

I thought the following would work, but it doesn't.

```
UPDATE dbo.tblFlatTVL 
SET TagType = NULL
WHERE TagType = 'NULL';
```

Comment: Your query should work.

Comment: The statement looks ok. Can you elaborate on how exactly doesn't it work? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: what happens when you do this and does it return any results?

select from dbo.tblFlatTVL where TagType = 'NULL';

If it does, then the update should work.

Comment: May be contains no printable chars? use `like '%NULL%' ( if other data don0t contais this substring )

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You query should work.  If by "nothing", you mean an empty string, then understand that an empty string is different from `NULL`:

```
Update dbo.tblFlatTVL
    set TagType = ''
    where TagType = 'NULL';
```

If the double quotes are part of the value, then you should include them in the comparison:

```
    where TagType = '"NULL"';
```

Comment: No, I didn't understand that NULL is different from an empty string.  I thought null was an empty string.  What I'm looking for is when I return results &/or export the results, I don't want any value appearing.  Right now NULL is returned.

Comment: With the following four queries, I get "Query executed successfully" and the DB displays the header rows with no rows returned underneath.

    select * from dbo.tblFlatTVL where TagType = NULL;
    select * from dbo.tblFlatTVL where TagType = 'NULL';
    select * from dbo.tblFlatTVL where TagType = '%NULL%';
    select * from dbo.tblFlatTVL where TagType = '';

Comment: When I run the following query, a row is returned.
select * from dbo.tblFlatTVL where PlateNumber = 'BT7G522';
However, when I select the field underneath the heading TagType, copy and paste the value elsewhere the value pasted is NULL.  When I use Excel to open the csv I imported into the database, NULL is displayed in the cell as text.

@Mureinik